# GIS Survey similar to Stack Overflow's Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, surveys

I think that it would be really helpful and insightful if there was an annual GIS Survey for gis.stackexchange in the model of Stack Overflow's Developer Survey.

Is there a particular way that this can be set up or progressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each year the Stack Overflow Developer Survey is [announced on the Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/23/our-2019-developer-survey-is-open-to-coders-everywhere/) and the most recent announcement began (with my bolding):

> What languages do you want to work with next year? Are you more
>   productive in an office or working from home? When did you write your
>   first line of code? We want to hear from you in our annual developer
>   survey! The survey, now in its ninth year, launches today and **anyone
>   who codes** is encouraged to participate.

I class myself amongst "anyone who codes" and, even though I participate here far more than at Stack Overflow, I fill out that survey each year, and have never felt a desire to complete a separate GIS Survey.  I would imagine that half the questions in a GIS Survey would be targeted at GIS Developers, and be a repeat of those from the Stack Overflow Developer Survey, and the other half would be targeted at GIS End Users and need to be developed by volunteers from this site.

However, there is no facility for site moderators to develop, release and analyse survey results for their own sites so, if you did want to get the Stack Overflow company to give individual sites that functionality, then you would need to post a feature request at the network-wide [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).